# Filter API connections with Plug

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to filter connections to my API.

In my `mix.exs` I've added:

```
pipeline :some_validation do
  plug VerifyLogicPlug
end

### INSIDE MY SCOPE:

  pipe_through [:some_validation, :previous_pipeline]
```

My plug looks like this:

```
defmodule VerifyLogicPlug do

  import Plug.Conn

  def init(options), do: options

  def call(conn, _options) do
    if some_logic do
      respond_blocked(conn)
    else
      conn # Continue the normal execution of the pipeline
    end
  end

  defp respond_blocked(conn) do
    response = %{
      error: %{
        status: 401,
        code: "BLOCKED",
        title: "BLOCKED"
      }
    }

    conn
    |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
    |> send_resp(status, Poison.encode!(response))
    halt(conn) # I've tried both with and without this line
  end
end
```

I get the desired response in the API:

```
{
    "error": {
        "title": "BLOCKED",
        "status": 401,
        "code": "BLOCKED"
    }
}
```

But in the server I get some errors, depending on whether I use `halt(conn)` or not.
With `halt(conn)`:

```
[error] #PID<0.1003.0> running MyProject.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET (...)
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Plug.Conn.NotSentError) a response was neither set nor sent from the connection
```

Without `halt(conn)`:

```
[error] #PID<0.1404.0> running MyProject.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: GET (...)
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (Plug.Conn.AlreadySentError) the response was already sent
```

What I want (I think) is to use `halt(conn)` but don't get the `Plug.Conn.NotSentError`, as a response is being sent. Any hints on what's missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the response twice.

Change the `respond_block` (which I suggest to rename to `block_request`) to:

```
conn
|> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
|> send_resp(status, Poison.encode!(response))
|> halt()
```

Comment: Oh, I see! So the difference is in my code I'm doing `halt` with the original `conn` as a parameter and in yours we're doing `halt` in the `conn` modified through the pipeline. Newbie mistake, I guess. Thanks!

Comment: It's difficult to exactly say which was the problem as I would need to see other parts of the application. You may wanna check the Plug.Conn source code here to understand how the AlreadySentError is raised: https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/v1.4.3/lib/plug/conn.ex#L388